# why do firefox load plugin which is not in its plugins directory?

Tags: firefox, plugins, browser-plugin

case: in my page, I need to download a plugin, I know firefox plugins directory is c:\program files(x86)\mozilla firefox\plugins. But I find a case, this downloaded plugin is located in C:\documents&settings[username]\plugins(I dont know how,maybe the user download the plugin early). And firefox try to load the plugin in wrong directory, but I can't find the plugin in firefox add-ons.

so why do firefox load plugin which is not in its plugins directory? anyone can show me firefox plugin load rule?

Answer (score 0):

> so why do firefox load plugin which is not in its plugins directory?

Plugins on Windows are mainly found [via the registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Windows_Installation_Using_the_Registry) - the plugin installer registers the plugins supported mimetypes and its path etc. under a special registry node.

In addition some directories are scanned (e.g. for common files and specific directories), but this shouldn't matter here and plugins shouldn't be installed into `FirefoxDir\plugins` (among other things they won't get picked up by other browsers that also support [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)).